# Unauthorized (401) when calling one localhost website from another

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-401

I have two websites set up on my local system running IIS 5.1 (on localhost). I am calling one website from another. I am working with ASP.NET, C# 2.0.

```
public static String executeWebRequest(string url, Boolean esmRequest)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        Stream requestStream = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader responseStream = null;
        string responseString;

        try
        {
            //post request
            request.Method = "POST";

            if (esmRequest)
            {
                //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerPassword"]);
            }
            else
            {
                //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerPassword"]);
            }

            requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(new byte[0], 0, 0);
            requestStream.Close();

            //get response
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
            responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (requestStream != null)
            {
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }

            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                responseStream.Close();
            }
        }

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

I run this code and get a 401 HTTP status code. 1 errorm whereas when I paste the same URL in the browser it executes perfectly.

I already have DisableLoopbackCheck enabled using http://support.microsoft.com/kb/89686/en-us

How can I resolve this?

Comment: the browser used (where its working ) is internet explorer by accident?

Comment: one more thing I forgot to mention I have windows authentication in both websites.

Comment: Directly pasting the URL works in all three - firefox, IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with this change

```
var cache = new CredentialCache();

NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESMServerPassword"]);

cache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", credential);
request.Credentials = cache;
```